# how to change filename of exported SSRS report

Tags: export, ssrs-2008, filenames

I have created SSRS report and want to change the name of file with adding Date to it.  I really appreciate your help.

Already tried  https://reportsyouneed.com/ssrs-adding-date-to-exported-filenames/ solution and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a perfect solution for this Issue.
[This link](https://reportsyouneed.com/ssrs-adding-date-to-exported-filenames/) works (very well) only if there  is no parameter required before export.

Code in this link try to get the file name when you click on the file, means when download not ready and report looking for initial inputs.

But my file has date parameters in the beginning to input. 
So I modify the code to wait till download is available and added to the end of  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js" file

```
function ModifyExportFileName(){
var rv=null;
var r= null;
var today =new Date();
var day= ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0"+ (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); 
var year = ("0"+ today.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
var text= "DD";
try{        
    rv=this.$find("ctl31");
        r=rv._getInternalViewer();
        var url=r.ExportUrlBase;
        var i = url.indexOf("FileName=");


    }
    catch(err)
        {
        //console.log(err);
        setTimeout(ModifyExportFileName,2000);
        return;
        }
    if(r==null)
        {
        setTimeout(ModifyExportFileName,2000);
        return;
        }
    else 
        {
        var url=r.ExportUrlBase;
        var i = url.indexOf("FileName=");
        var j = url.indexOf("&",i+1);
        var oldFileName= url.substring(i+9,j);
        var filename=text.concat(year,month,day)
        r.ExportUrlBase= url.substring(0,i) + 'FileName=' + filename+ url.substring(j);
        }
//console.log(filename);
setTimeout(ModifyExportFileName,2000);
}
ModifyExportFileName();
```

I need date as a filename so date is added as "filename". you can change it as required

Comment: can you please provide a solution code that fits the question requirement?

Comment: I have provided the code in above solution. "var filename=text.concat(year,month,day)" is new file name. You can put anything here. you need to add this code block in the end of  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js" file.

Comment: @kulvir, how did you install that ReportingServices.js file? I have multiple SSRS versions installed on 7 different Windows desktop and Windows servers and have never seen any file by that name on my installations. In fact there is no /ReportManager subfolder on any of my servers. What installation is that a part of?

Answer (score 1):

An easy alternative might be

An alternative approach to creating unique files for every delivery is to include a timestamp in the file name. To do this, add the @timestamp variable to the file name (for example, CompanySales@timestamp). With this approach, the file name is unique by definition, so it will never be overwritten.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/file-share-delivery-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15